# Where is the certificate created using makecert.exe?

Tags: wcf, netsh, makecert

I need to have a "http**s**" enabled self hosted WCF service. Given that there need to be a certificate to have the service "s" enabled, I created the certificate using the following two commands in the same order:

```
makecert.exe -sv SignRoot.pvk -cy authority -r signroot.cer -a sha1 -n "CN=AuthorityName" -ss my -sr localmachine
```

and then

```
makecert.exe -iv SignRoot.pvk -ic signroot.cer -cy end -pe -n CN="localhost" -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localmachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12
```

Now to configure the port using SSL, netsh has to be used, which requires to be supplied with arguments certhash and appid. My best understanding is that I need to have the certificate to get these values. But where is the certificate I just created!!!????

I did try certmgr.msc, it showed the root as "Certificates - Current User". How to make it show the "localmachine" certificates, as marked by -sr option?

Again, where are my certificates!!??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificates are in the .CER files you specify on the command-line.

To use them you need to import them into the certificate store using the MMC/Certificate snap-in.

Comment: thank you for directing to MMC/certificate snap-in. I was able to see the certificates. I had actually started creating the certificate in one of my stores, "myCertStore". Using netsh with this new certificate failed with "SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 1312
A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated." I moved the certificate from "myCertStore" to "Personal". This made the netsh register the port successfuly.

Comment: it''s not there!

Comment: @user1034912: What is not where?